# Javascript || React Native how to use map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Image } from "react-native";

const Icons = [
  { name: "Food", uri: require("./images/Food.png") },
  { name: "Mart", uri: require("./images/mart.png") },
  { name: "Car",  uri: require("./images/car.png")  }
];

const IconSelection = Icons.map((icons) => (
  <View>
    <Image source={icons.uri} />
    <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{icons.name}</Text>
  </View>
));

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default IconSelection;
```

Is my way of adding images to my const Icons correct? Basically I want to create like a list of Icons using images and able to call them. Previously my method is basically handcode them but I found it is very messy. I think maps() could help me but I'm not really sure how to use it too. Thank you.

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import IconSelection from "./icons";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <IconSelection />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

It says Check the render method of `app`. The error source is pointing require().

Comment: What makes you think it's incorrect? Do you have any errors?

Comment: well, maybe a bit of naming (`map`'s cb argument `icons` be rather `icon` wouldn't it?; or desctucture ... `.map(({name, url}) => ( ... Image source={url} .. )` , otherwise seems ok ..

Comment: Yes there is error. This is another file.js and I want to add these inside app.js.

Comment: It seems it should work but please edit the post with the related errors, So in this case, it is better to understand and help.

Comment: I just edit my post. The error is require().

Comment: IconSelection is not an element, it's an array of elements. `const IconSelection = () => Icons.map...` would solve it.

Comment: It says the Array.prototype.map callback must be a function @UgurEren

Comment: @ShinnySkin ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an array of items.

You most likely need a new component that wraps your icons. Something like this

```
const IconSelection = () => {
 return <>
   Icons.map((icons) => (
    <View>
     <Image source={icons.uri} />
     <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{icons.name}</Text>
    </View>
  )
 </>
}
```

You also need to make sure that the paths to images are correct and you have proper loaders for that file type.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your ways and it didnt show up any error. However, my image and my text is not shown.

Comment: I also add another { } after the Icons.map((icons) => (